# Enforcing match order in a RegEx

Tags: regex

I'm parsing some search query text for ISBNs. Each line may contain zero or more ISBN10s, zero or more ISBN13s, and other unrelated digits. The text has been sanitized to contain only `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]`, but there may be whitespace between related digits. I've successfully written some regular expression fragments to parse the text, but I'm unsure how to get them to execute in the order I want.

First, here's a sample line of text from the data:

> foo ISBN10 013 284 1649 0132841648 Web ISBN13 9 78013 2841641 9780132841641 2013 bar

I need to (in this order):

1. Search the entire string for `([9][7][8-9]\d{10})`.
2. Search **only things that weren't already matched** for `(\d{10})`
3. Search **only things that weren't already matched** for `([9]\s*[7]\s*[8-9]\s*(\s*\d){10})`
4. Search **only things that weren't already matched** for `(\d(\s*\d){9})`

This accomplishes searching for complete ISBN13s, then complete ISBN10s, then fragmented ISBN13s, and finally fragmented ISBN10s. However, if I simply paste them together separated by `|`, the RegEx engine wants to evaluate (1,2,3,4) for each character. How do I accomplish searching the entire string for expression #1 before even thinking about evaluating #2?

Comment: Are you sure you can't to it in one pass?  This regex works for me: [`\b((?:[9]\s*[7]\s*[8-9]\s*)?\d(?:\s*\d){9})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/dN1qG5/1)

Comment: That works pretty well! It doesn't work for all possible cases, though. Consider `foo ISBN10013 284 1649 0132841648 Web ISBN13 9 78013 2841641 9770132841641 2013 bar`. It doesn't catch ISBN10s: 1001328416 & 9770132841

Comment: To further elaborate, word boundaries unfortunately aren't going to work here, because there may be valid ISBNs beginning immediately adjacent to words. For example, `word123456789 0` and `word12 345678 90word` are both valid.

Comment: Then how about lookarounds?  I used word boundaries because they're supported in all of the Perl-derived flavors, and you didn't say which flavor you're using.  This regex satisfies your elaborated requirements and it works in everything but JavaScript:  [`(?<!\d)((?:[9]\s*[7]\s*[8-9]\s*)?\d(?:\s*\d){9})(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/dN1qG5/2)

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this, I really appreciate the help. There's still two issues with that though: it doesn't catch two (or more) ISBNs stuck together, like `12345678901234567890`, and it won't grab the 10/13 digits out of a longer sequence, like `97845678901234`. The RegEx fragments in my question would grab those. I'm going to play around with your code a bit and see if I can't get those two situations matched.

Answer (score 1):

Perform four `replaceAll`s and remove the successful matches at each step (i.e., replace them with `""`).

Comment: That will work perfectly in this instance, since I'm writing this in Java, and there's a `replaceAll` method. However, I'm still curious if there's a language-agnostic/'native' way to implement this.

Comment: I'm unaccepting, as this actually isn't going to work well for me. Turns out I need to get start/end substring indexes for each occurrence, and using `replace` really makes that difficult.